# How to disable all windows 7 error message popups?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I would like to disable all windows 7 error popups including windows has detected a hard disk problem. I know it is best to know about these messages but this is for a corporate customer of mine who has 1000's of machines, I run pro-active scans on SMART and all sorts but have come up with a disk defect which I am sorting with a manufacturer, in the meantime I need the end user to not be interrupted by any errors as the machines are effectively Point Of Sale machines.

I have Error Reporting disabled already, but the hard drive messages still showed up. The Error Reporting, I assume, is the "Windows is trying to fix something" popups.

I will need to do this via script, which is not an issue, but need a registry only way of turning off ALL error popups. I have all the access I need to do this just not the registry values!

Please note that this is specifically for windows 7

Comment: Just change the disk and be done with it - silencing the error messages is dangerously different to fixing the problem.

Comment: These are warrantied, I am sorting that bit out separately, but I need the messages gone for now.

Comment: So you have 1000s of machines, and not a single spare disk to use in the meantime? WOW!

Comment: I appreciate your sarcasm towards this issue, but we have had multiple failures showing an odd bad sector. I just need a way of suppressing the message. I assume from your lack of direct answers to my actual question that you don't know how to do it, can we just leave this now to someone who can help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank goodness the warning message is harcoded into the system tray, so as long as you run it (visibly or not), it will pop up.

Comment: The message is: 'windows has detected a hard disk problem' and pops up as an error message where you can click 'Start backup process' or ' ask me later' or something like that. I just want that error not to pop up. There is no explorer actually running on these, so no systray.

Comment: Run 'strings' on explorer.exe - it is there. So you run systray invisibly.